# Equivalent of .RowSource for Text Box

Tags: ms-access, vba

What is the equivalent of **.RowSource** for a text box?

For example, I have assigned a ComboBox value using the following:

```
With Forms("fmOne").SearchLname
    .RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT(LName) From tbCase;"
    Call .Requery
End With
```

Is there a textbox equivalent?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since a TextBox can only display a single value (there is no dropdown of values to select from), there is no need for anything like the `RowSource` property.

You can bind the TextBox to a value though, the same as you can do with any other control, by using the `ControlSource` property. That will automatically fill in the apropriate value from the current record if you bound the underlying form to a data source.

This is, however, not comparable to the `RowSource` property of a combo box.

Comment: What if I want to set a textbox or some other box that displays a value and base it on a combobox selection. If combobox is this then display this value from this table for example. I think maybe textbox is not the right vehicle to do this...

Comment: That seems like a different question. You could do that by retrieving the desired value in the `AfterUpdate` event of the combo box by means of `DLookup()` or `CodeDB.OpenRecordset()` and write that value to the text box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression as control source of a textbox, e.g.

The third column of the selected row of a multi-column combobox on the same form:

```
=MyCombobox.Column(2)
```

A `DLookup` query based on another textbox:

```
=DLookup("foo", "myTable", "bar = '" & [OtherTextbox] & "'")
```

This will need a `.Requery` though after updating [OtherTextbox], I think.